# Xamarin forms detect upi:// URL and open installed UPI applications using PCL

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, webview

Is there any way to detect upi:// URL in Xamarin forms PCL? I have tried below code but no success yet.

Note: Not looking for android and iOS based solution in this case.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace xamaringformwithIntentUPI
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            MyWebview.Source = "https://payment1.atomtech.in/paynetz/epi/fts?login=1191&pass=NCA@1234&ttype=NBFundTransfer&prodid=NCA&amt=1.00&txncurr=INR&txnscamt=0&clientcode=007&txnid=T2&custacc=1234567890&date=26/06/2018&ru=https://payment.atomtech.in/paynetzclient/ResponseParam.jsp&signature=b8f1c0972cd5f664a5fb41e0b3e5860a3c3bfd66835e5635940cf38245b234063090669ad691b6d6265491bf0510ea07d890530bd5b6309d31c81294b8f122ce&udf2=sagar@gmail.com&udf3=8888888888";
            MyWebview.Navigating += Webview_Navigating;

        }

        private void Webview_Navigating(object sender, WebNavigatingEventArgs e)
        {
            var url = e.Url;
            Console.WriteLine("url detected = " + url);
            if (url.StartsWith("upi://"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("upi url detected = ");
                Console.WriteLine(url);
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: is the link a normal `<a>` or some javascript code?

Comment: @jason this is a link normal <a>

Comment: is the event handler being fired?  Have you traced it in the debugger?

Comment: yes, all other available links are detected but not this UPI url

Comment: Based on your code ,I created a simple demo , method `Webview_Navigating`  was triggered after I deployed the demo to my device. And since the url doesn't  start with  `upi://`, so code `url.StartsWith("upi://")` will return `false`.